# How to convert a list of lists of lists into a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have

```
testlist = [[["a", "b", "c"]], [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]]
```

and want

```
finalist = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

I've tried

```
finalist = [[item for subsublist in sublist for item in subsublist] for sublist in testlist]
```

but this gives me

```
finalist = [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]]
```

Comment: This is a common question and there's already a ton of detailed answers in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists I tested `list(itertools.chain(*testlist))` on your data and it does just what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this on your input. I think you just have to worry about the sublists and unpack them. Your approach is flattening sublists first which is why that last portion was wrong

```py
[l for s in testlist for l in s]
```